# Problem viewing webpage on default web browser of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox

For last few days I cannot view Google "Inbox" on Firefox 37.0.2. It loads initially and then blacks out. There was no problem a few days back.

[image]
[image]

Firefox when run from terminal gives a lot of errors.

```
XXXXXX@Firnen:~$ firefox

(process:1359): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:1359): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:1359): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:1359): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:1359): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
get_contentWindow@chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml:404:54
get_securityUI@chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml:654:17
browser_XBL_Constructor@chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml:778:17
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
create@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/frame/utils.js:60:3
make@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/panel/utils.js:260:25
setup@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/panel.js:152:16
@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/disposable.js:48:56
dispatch@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/method/core.js:119:12
Disposable<.initialize@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/disposable.js:69:17
constructor@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/heritage.js:146:23
exports.main@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://jid0-rawjeli57dra4jx9cciym5qzuqu-at-jetpack/dictionary-extension/lib/main.js:110:22
run@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:151:1
startup/</<@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:86:7
Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:870:23
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:749:7
this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:691:37
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
create@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/frame/utils.js:60:3
make@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/panel/utils.js:263:19
setup@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/panel.js:152:16
@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/disposable.js:48:56
dispatch@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/method/core.js:119:12
Disposable<.initialize@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/disposable.js:69:17
constructor@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/heritage.js:146:23
exports.main@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://jid0-rawjeli57dra4jx9cciym5qzuqu-at-jetpack/dictionary-extension/lib/main.js:110:22
run@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:151:1
startup/</<@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:86:7
Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:870:23
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:749:7
this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:691:37
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
create@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/frame/utils.js:60:3
make@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/panel/utils.js:260:25
setup@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/panel.js:152:16
@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/disposable.js:48:56
dispatch@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/method/core.js:119:12
Disposable<.initialize@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/disposable.js:69:17
constructor@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/heritage.js:146:23
@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://firefox-at-ghostery-dot-com/ghostery/lib/background.js:79:10
evaluate@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js:267:19
load@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js:318:5
CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:129:18
main@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js:684:10
run@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:145:19
startup/</<@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:86:7
Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:870:23
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:749:7
this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:691:37
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
create@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/frame/utils.js:60:3
make@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/panel/utils.js:263:19
setup@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/panel.js:152:16
@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/disposable.js:48:56
dispatch@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/method/core.js:119:12
Disposable<.initialize@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/disposable.js:69:17
constructor@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/heritage.js:146:23
@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://firefox-at-ghostery-dot-com/ghostery/lib/background.js:79:10
evaluate@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js:267:19
load@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js:318:5
CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:129:18
main@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js:684:10
run@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:145:19
startup/</<@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:86:7
Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:870:23
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:749:7
this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:691:37
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
create@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/frame/utils.js:60:3
make@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/panel/utils.js:260:25
setup@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/panel.js:152:16
@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/disposable.js:48:56
dispatch@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/method/core.js:119:12
Disposable<.initialize@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/disposable.js:69:17
constructor@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/heritage.js:146:23
@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://jid1-j3kix1n7uxrjxq-at-jetpack/languagetoolfx/lib/main.js:303:11
evaluate@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js:267:19
load@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js:318:5
CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:129:18
main@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js:684:10
run@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:145:19
startup/</<@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:86:7
Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:870:23
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:749:7
this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:691:37
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
create@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/frame/utils.js:60:3
make@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/panel/utils.js:263:19
setup@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/panel.js:152:16
@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/disposable.js:48:56
dispatch@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/method/core.js:119:12
Disposable<.initialize@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/disposable.js:69:17
constructor@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/heritage.js:146:23
@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://jid1-j3kix1n7uxrjxq-at-jetpack/languagetoolfx/lib/main.js:303:11
evaluate@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js:267:19
load@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js:318:5
CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:129:18
main@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js:684:10
run@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:145:19
startup/</<@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/XXXXXX/.mozilla/firefox/d16rq2n0.default/extensions/jid0-raWjElI57dRa4jx9CCiYm5qZUQU@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:86:7
Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:870:23
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:749:7
this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:691:37
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
get_contentWindow@chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml:404:54
get_securityUI@chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml:654:17
browser_XBL_Constructor@chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml:778:17
SelfSupportBackendInternal._makeHiddenBrowser/<@resource://app/modules/SelfSupportBackend.jsm:192:7
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Could you add which Ubuntu Version and flavour you're using?

Comment: @Fabby I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS with unity. Here is the uname output: Linux 3.13.0-51-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 15 12:08:34 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Looks like a bug in either Firefox or its drawing library.

Comment: @DavidFoerster When initiated from the terminal it displayed 168 lines long error messages. It's too long to put here. First few lines are like this: (process:1359): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
(firefox:1359): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised
(firefox:1359): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised
(firefox:1359): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Firefox 38.0 ovet Ubuntu-gnome 14.04.

Setting default scaling (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>) sets it black, but zooming in one step (either by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+[mouse wheel up]) fixes it.

Zooming out to default scaling again or less (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+[mouse wheel down]) blacks it again.

Hope this helps until a fix is released.

Comment: It actually helped, Thanx!. I hope they'll fix it someday.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this issue too, be it white and with Linux Mint 17.1 64bit (based on 14.04 LTS). First Inbox worked fine, but now Inbox is pretty much unusable with Firefox. Switching to a fresh Firefox profile didn't solve the problem, weirdly the glitches were now mostly black.

Do you have any scaling enabled? I've got it enabled, because otherwise everything gets really tiny on my HiDPI-display. Turning it off or zooming in or out did the trick for me. Suddenly there were no more glitches, perhaps this work-around will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to ubuntu 15.04 solved the issue. ubuntu 15.04 has firefox 39.0.3 by default.